# Regexing html, still under progress?

Tags: discussion

Under one of the most popular answers on SO - [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), I see this:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being
>   resolved. For more info visit meta.

I think more than 2 years have been passed, before being locked by Marc Gravell.

Is it still being resolved, or is the message simply put?

Is it still active?

Comment: Personally, I think the question should be either completely locked, or completely unlocked. Locking just that top answer messes with the voting. As it is right now, the other answers will eventually overtake Bobince's answer - which isn't reflective of how people would have voted if the field were level.

Answer (score 7):

It's a standard message.

There are no disputes, it is just locked to protect the question from further editing, as it kept being defaced or 'improved' by well-meaning editors with no idea what they were doing.

Locking just this answer this way includes that message, but it is likely that the defacements will never go away, so neither will the lock.

See [Why does the RegEx answer keep getting locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134933)

There is a [bug / feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108404/the-historical-significance-lock-reason-on-answers-still-references-this-questi) to have the lock message updated to something a little less confusing.

Comment: Unlocking the answer will set Zalgo free. We really don't want *that* to happen!